# Yammer embed feed is throwing 404 not found error intermittently on sharepoint page

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, yammer, facebook-opengraph

We are loading yammer embedded feed on our page using an Open Graph snippet. We are attempting to load it on the window.onload event. Intermittently it seems to be throwing an HTTP 404. These are examples:

1. "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). POST -
   https://www.yammer.com/office365 "
2. "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR)GET - https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/open_graph_objects?url=myurl&properties%5Burl%5D=myurl&properties%5Btitle%5D=mytitle&properties%5Btype%5D=page&properties%5Bimage%5D=&properties%5Bdescription%5D=&properties%5Bsite_name%5D=&properties%5Bfetch%5D=true&properties%5Bignore_canonical_url%5D=false&properties%5Bprivate%5D=true&private=false&_=1556012959748 "

This is the snippet that we are using:

```html
var attach = function () {
    var yammerGroupId = "";
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('mydomain.sharepoint.com') > 0) {
        yammerGroupId = 0000000;
    }
    else {
        yammerGroupId = 0000000;
    }
   
    myDescription = "";
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: "#embedded-feed",
        feedType: "open-graph",
        config: {
            use_sso: true,
            header: false,
            footer: false,
            showOpenGraphPreview: false,
            defaultToCanonical: false,
            hideNetworkName: false,
            defaultGroupId: yammerGroupId,
            promptText: "Comment on this page..."
        },
        objectProperties: {
            type: "page",
            url:window.location.href,
            fetch: true,
            title:document.title,
            private: true,
            ignore_canonical_url: false,
            description: ""
        }
    });

}


if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', attach, false)
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', attach)
}
```

Please note that the Window onload is getting fired as expected. It works fine 7/10 times, but gives 404 error intermittently on Edge, IE, and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that you get a 404 from `/api/v1/open_graph_objects` per the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/open_graph_objects) when the URL passed as a parameter isn't an Open Graph Object (OGO) in the Yammer network. Check the URL parameter is actually valid.

For example, you set `url: myUrl`, but you are probably best to set this directly with `"url": "window.location.href"` since the value doesn't seem to be set right from your code. Use the [configuration tool](https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure) to work out better JavaScript to use since your code looks invalid.

Comment: Hi Brain thanks for your inputs , myUrl in my code is set to "window.location.href" already, sorry I missed to mention that in the snippet .The same code runs fine 7/10 times but intermittently throws 404 error or does not the feed at all .Checked in configuration tool as you mentioned and it loads fine there.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually set? If the code is running async it might not be set. Try setting it explicitly to some well known site URL like microsoft.com or yahoo.com.

Comment: as suggested i tried setting up the url explicitly still no luck .